# How to choose the number of decimals in C

Tags: c, format, decimal

I have to make a program in C, the program have to calculate a zero of a function using  Newton–Raphson method, The program should also ask the user the number of decimal places.

This is a summary of the code:

```
long double result=4.2367423847652347624523645237642
int decimal;
printf("How many decimal places do you want? \n);
scanf("%i",&decimal);
printf("The result is: %.**Lf"result);
```

I have the problem in **, in case I write 20**, in there should be 20 (%.20Lf)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
printf("The result is: %.*Lf", decimal, result);
```

Comment: Note: Use `"%#.*Lf"` if you want to also see the decimal point when `decimal == 0`.